# mouse hover pop up

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, web

So just now I was looking over other people's portfolio websites to get some inspiration on what to do with my portfolio website.

And after some browsing I came across a neat little website

http://www.brianclaire.com/

Scrolling down to where the portfolio is.

I was wondering how did the designer managed to add a transparent layer with text over the tablet looking image while toggling it with the mouse over and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in developer tools text is wrap in anchor tag and "overlay" css class is applied to it.

```
.overlay {
    width: 101%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

last four properties are used to make element look transparent.